# Formatting dynamic dropdownlist text (money)

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to format the text of my drop down list but nothing seems to work. Here is my code below:

Drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSalary" CssClass="ddlBox" 
    CausesValidation="true" AutoPostBack="true" 
    onselectedindexchanged="ddlSalary_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Code behind:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlSalary.DataSource = Placements.DropDownPopulating("Placement_Salary_From");
        ddlSalary.DataBind();

        ddlSalary.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Salary --", "0"));
```

Results:

```
6.0000
200.0000
1000.0000
```

But I would like:

```
£6
£200
£1000
```

I have tried using:

```
ddlSalary.DataTextFormatString = "{0:C}";
```

**EDIT**

Populating drop down list:

```
public static List<string> DropDownPopulating(string selectedFilter)
    {
        List<string> returnVal = new List<string> { };
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["websiteContent"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            string SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT " + selectedFilter + " FROM Placements";
            using (var CMD = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlCon))
            {
                using (var DR = CMD.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (DR.Read())
                    {
                        returnVal.Add(DR[selectedFilter].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```

Comment: What is the data type of the field you are using for `DataTextField`?

Comment: Please include code from `Placements.DropDownPopulating`. If you are setting the `DataTextField` to column that is a `decimal`, what you did should work. It looks like for some reason it is a `string`, so the "C" doesn't work.

Comment: @mikesmithdev I have included that as an edit in my original post.

Comment: The problem is you are return a string. If instead you returned a `List<decimal>`, it would work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `numeric` datatype if you want the formatting to work:

```
public static List<T> DropDownPopulating<T>(string selectedFilter)
{
    var returnVal = new List<T>();
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["websiteContent"].ConnectionString;
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT " + selectedFilter + " FROM Placements";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // if you are using .NET 4.5
                returnVal.Add(reader.GetFieldValue<T>(reader.GetOrdinal(selectedFilter)));

                // if you are using .NET 4.0 or older:
                // returnVal.Add((T)reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(selectedFilter)));
            }
        }
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

and then:

```
ddlSalary.DataSource = Placements.DropDownPopulating<decimal>("Placement_Salary_From");
ddlSalary.DataTextFormatString = "{0:C}";
ddlSalary.DataBind();
```

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I was using one function to populate multiple dropdownlists. I have seperated this out for the salary dropdownlist, which means I no longer need to pass a parameter, how would you alter this?

Comment: Depending on the type of the field you are querying you always need to specify the data type. In your case you were casting everything to string but you cannot apply any format to a string.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I usually populate my class properties with a datareader, but as this is a format I have not used before I am unsure how to carry out the same action.

Answer (score 0):

use this query to get data.....

```
  select '$'+Cast((Cast(Price as int))as varchar) from TableName
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get a "," inbetween larger numbers?

Comment: This isn't a good way to do this. You can format the data as needed in the code behind. Now it can no longer be manipulated, like summing the prices together, etc, as it is a string. Also, the Price column would be a DECIMAL or MONEY.... not an INT.

Comment: @lauw0203 that is what formatting with "C" is for... and why you shouldn't try formatting your front-end code on the database side. What you originally did should work fine assuming that the data type was a decimal/ etc.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev, I tried the way Amit suggested in an SQL query but my function does not seem to like it. In response to your question, do you mean how the numbers are formatted in the database? If so, money.

Comment: @MikeSmitDev....in modern time its lots of load is already on server....so its always better get data as u show in front from database...and about manipulating ...u use dropdownlist.Value property....i m send to to populate only text field....bcz it just to show use....ok.......

Comment: @AmitSingh No, it is really never better to do presentation formatting in the data layer. Do you use [multitier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)?

Comment: what ever its architexture @mikeSmithDev....in todays mthousand of people accessing the site at time....to enhance server performance.....its better to get data in formatted way from database....bcz it very less load there and todays databse is very fast and efficent.....i mm not trying to prove wrong...but thats what we think while we develope apps.......thats y i answer according to that

Comment: @amitsingh, it works in an SQL query but my function stops working when I include it in there.

Comment: can show ur function...if u dont have problem
Sqlcommad cmd=new Sqlcommand(query,con); DataTable dt=cmd.ExecuteCommand(); dropDownmlist.datasource=dt;

Comment: @amitsingh, I have edited my first post and included my function.